# Creating a popup with values from a form JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a new window with values received from textfield with id "name";

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" id="name">
</form>

<button onclick="openWindow();">Open</button>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
function openWindow() {
newWindow = window.open("", null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  

newWindow.document.write("<h1>"+document.myForm.name.value+"</h1>");
}
```

It does it ok, but why does it empty the form values?
And how can i center this new window? Maybe height=window.height()/2 ?

Comment: Create a popup? Or a window? Two different things. Why not use alert()

Comment: @GeekByDesign window sorry, i need this new window to be interactive later on, to change values etc...

Comment: Because you aren't declaring `myForm` as the actual element. Or at all.

Comment: @SpencerMay where should i declare it, outside the openWIndow method, like var someText[] = document.myForm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable the onclick event, it's submitting the form.
Add this to the form tag, then at the bottom of the function return false.
    `onsubmit="return openWindow();">`

Comment: as for centering the window put` var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);` in your function and put`top='+top+', left='+left) in your window open

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my end, tried your code. Dont forget to write something inside the input box, before you click the button. if it doesn't work

Try this instead:

```
newWindow.document.write("<h1>"+document.getElementById('name').value+"</h1>");
```

Comment: pff neither works, still empties the form when the new window pops up